# How to get return value for expect in python

Tags: python

Hi I'm new to python programming.

I have written python script to connect remote host and execute few commands.
I have used pexpect for this

```
host = sys.argv[1]
user = sys.argv[2]
password = sys.argv[3]

child = pexpect.spawn("ssh -l %s %s "%(user, host))
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline(password)
child.expect('[#\$] ')
child.sendline('command1')
child.expect('[#\$] ')
print child.before
child.sendline('command2')
child.expect('[#\$] ')
print child.before
```

Here I want to execute command 2 if command 1 is successful else I want to send output as NULL and exit.

I have tried this using if condition but it is not working:

```
child.sendline('command1')
i=child.expect('[#\$] ')
if i:
    child.sendline('command2')
    child.expect('[#\$] ')
else:
    print "NULL NULL"
```

But this is not working.

How to capture the return codes of pexpect and how we will validate those values?

Comment: have you tried running `echo $?` (and `child.expect` a result of 0) after running `command1`.  or just run `command1 && command2` on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `expect()`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect) states:

> This returns the index into the pattern list. If the pattern was not a list this returns index 0 on a successful match.

Thus your statement `i=child.expect('[#\$] ')` will set `i` to `0` when the pattern is a successful match.  Since the "command1" program will (presumably) exit and then the shell will provide a prompt, your pattern will match whether the command was successful or failed.

Since I know nothing about your "command1", I can't suggest a concrete solution.  I can only abstractly describe ways to approach solving this.  If "command1" produces output that indicates whether it succeeded or failed then you can look for that output.  You can either match it as part of your "expect" call, or you can look for it in the `child.match` attribute or in the `child.before` attribute.  If the program/command itself doesn't provide output for matching, then as suggested in a comment, add the shell command `echo $?` (or maybe some variation like `echo "Result of command1: $?"`).  Then you can match on that to extract the program's exit code.